# как увеличить счетчик в рекурсии?

Tags: php

```
function r($b,$a){
    $new_mas = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach($b as $uniq){

        var_dump($i);


        $k = array_search($uniq,$a);
        if($k!==false){
            $new_mas[]=$uniq;   
            unset($a[$k]);
        }else{
            unset($b[$i]);
        }
        if($i==(sizeof($b)-1)){
            if(sizeof($a)){
                $new_mas=array_merge($new_mas,r($b,$a));
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $new_mas; 
}

$dddd = r($b,$a);
```

Функция выводит

```
int(0)
int(1)
int(0)
int(1)
int(0)
int(1)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы счетчик постоянно увеличивался на 1, а не обнулялся в каком-то моменте. 
Подскажите, что неправильно ?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант передавать счетчик рекурсии третьим параметром функции через ссылку:

```
function r($b,$a,&$i=0){

...
   if(sizeof($a)){
       $new_mas=array_merge($new_mas,r($b,$a,$i));
   }
....
}

$i=0;
r($b,$a,$i);
var_dump($i);
```

Но при запуске функции $i можно не передавать, а отлавливать только внутри.

Answer (score 0):

Происходит это по той причине, что у вас в начале функции присвается значение `0` переменной `i`. Значит, при каждом её вызове, `i` становится равной `0`.

Чтобы этого не происходило, достаточно вынести строку `$i = 0;` за пределы фунции.

Comment: вынес за пределы. Но теперь выводит так 
`int(0)
int(1)
int(1)
int(1)
int(2)
int(4)
`