# Как увеличить счетчик в рекурсии на единицу?

Tags: php, рекурсия

```
function r($b,$a){
    $new_mas = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach($b as $uniq){

        var_dump($i);


        $k = array_search($uniq,$a);
        if($k!==false){
            $new_mas[]=$uniq;   
            unset($a[$k]);
        }else{
            unset($b[$i]);
        }
        if($i==(sizeof($b)-1)){
            if(sizeof($a)){
                $new_mas=array_merge($new_mas,r($b,$a));
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $new_mas; 
}

$dddd = r($b,$a);
```

Функция выводит

```
int(0)
int(1)
int(0)
int(1)
int(0)
int(1)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы счетчик постоянно увеличивался на 1, а не обнулялся в каком-то моменте. Подскажите, что неправильно ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как увеличить счетчик в рекурсии?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138983/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
function r($b,$a){
    global $i;
    $new_mas = array();

    foreach($b as $uniq){

        var_dump($i);


        $k = array_search($uniq,$a);
        if($k!==false){
            $new_mas[]=$uniq;   
            unset($a[$k]);
        }else{
            unset($b[$i]);
        }
        if($i==(sizeof($b)-1)){
            if(sizeof($a)){
                $new_mas=array_merge($new_mas,r($b,$a));
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $new_mas;
}

$dddd = r($b,$a);
```

максимально топорный вариант.

Comment: выводит `int(0)
int(1)
int(1)
int(1)
int(2)
int(4)
`

Comment: а можно примеры массивов b и a?

Comment: `$a = Array
(
    [116] => mail.ru
    [121] => mail.ru
    [122] => mail.ru
    [129] => yandex.ua
)`

Comment: `$b=Array
(
    [116] => mail.ru
    [129] => yandex.ua
)`